# Angular $http transformResponse and cache

Tags: angularjs

Is the response from an Angular $http request cached before or after any transformResponse functions have been applied?

Use case:
My client's REST API returns a lot of metadata (most of which I don't need) so I don't want to cache the entire response.  I'd like to apply a specific transformResponse for each different API end-point that copies only the fields I need into a new object\array and dispose of the original.  I would then like the new object to automatically be cached.  This should be nice and easy if the return data from transformResponse is cached.

Comment: See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#caching ~ *"When the cache is enabled, `$http` stores **the response from the server** in the specified cache"*

Answer (score 3):

Apparently is cached before transforming, as you can see in [$http#717](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L717) sendReq is called before transformResponse, and in [$http#958](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L958) you can see sendReq does the caching

Maybe you can be sure by doing a test